# Easy ode question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I forget ODE. Please solve this. Thanks. 
$M=M(u,v))$

$M_{uu}+M=0$

I guess I need to take $D=\frac{d M}{d u}$
Then I need to write $D^2+1=0$

But I cannot remember properly.

Comment: Find the roots $\alpha, \beta$ of $D^2+1$ to find the basis of solutions $\left(u\mapsto e^{\alpha u}, u\mapsto e^{\beta u}\right)$.